# Custom fields using Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm starting to write a project and its my first time using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework (since now I've used PHP for around 5 years).

I got categories and posts, each category has to have its own unique filters that can be strings or Booleans (I'll get them via textboxes or checkboxes). I'm starting to get confused when designing the entities.

I'm using code-first approach but don't know how to set-up custom fields in Entity Framework. If I'd design that in PHP and pure SQL, I think that in order to keep it perform good, I'd create extra columns on the fly (e.g. "filter_1", "filter_2") and then create mapping table that contains the description of the field, the type, etc. and I didn't figure out if this kind of implementation is possible in EF.

I've thought about some options:
- I can create the filter using many-to-many relationships when creating a filters and filters-values tables and when creating a post add the filter values into that table. The main con about it is he performance - I'll most likely have 40k+ rows and more than 20 custom filters for sure... so searching and data fetching will be too slow...
- I thought about serializing the filtered values into some form of content, for example into bytes array and then only desterilize it - but the problem is that I won't be able to search within that...
- I can use the traditional ADO.NET way in order to create my initial idea (that I've described when talking about PHP - using the "filter_N" columns) but that'd create too much mess with EF...

There's any other way to achieve my goal (to create custom filters)? any way to create custom fields using EF?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Entity framework is not a tool for scenarios where you expect to change database at runtime. If you want to use EF you should have separate tables for filters and values and correctly set indexes to solve performance issue. 40k rows is not a big deal when you set indexes correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll follow your advice and create it using models.
Can you mark your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good way offhand to implement this in the Entity Framework.  If you really wanted to use the Entity Framework I believe you could design your database tables in such a way that you wouldn't have to create the extra columns on the fly.  You could have separate tables to hold the filters and relate them back to categories.